# Access background worker from a different class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, backgroundworker

I'm separating out logic from one class to another in my Windows Form application. When all in one class, it works fine but I am moving the logic to it's own respective classes now. Having some issues getting at the backgroundWorker from a different class.

I have in class A

```
public partial class ClassA : Form
    BackgroundWorker essentialBgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public ClassA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //essentialBgWorker
            essentialBgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(essentialBgWorker_DoWork);
            essentialBgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(essentialBgWorker_ProgressChanged);
            essentialBgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(essentialBgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            essentialBgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }
```

That is a form that has a button which when clicked, copies files to another directory.

```
private void copyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clickedButton = ((Button)sender).Name.ToString();
    itemsChanged = ((Button)sender).Text.ToString();
    essentialBgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This runs the background worker:

```
public void essentialBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string buttonSender = clickedButton; //copyButton, deleteButton, etc.
    switch (buttonSender)
    {
        case "copyButton":
            //this is pseudocode - the important part being that this is where I would call the method from the other class
            ClassB.copyDocuments();
            break;
        case "deleteButton":
            //this is pseudocode - the important part being that this is where I would call the method from the other class
            ClassB.deleteDocuments();
            break;
        default:
            essentialBgWorker.CancelAsync();
            break;
    }
}
```

In my other class (`ClassB`) for this example I have the method that is called when the button is clicked (should be handling the logic).

```
public void copyDocuments()
{
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    //
    //the logic that handles copying the files
    //gets the filecount!

    //Report to the background worker
    int totalFileCount = fileCount;
    int total = totalFileCount; //total things being transferred
    for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++) //report those numbers
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        int percents = (i * 100) / total;
        classA.essentialBgWorker.ReportProgress(percents, i);

        //2 arguments:
        //1. procenteges (from 0 t0 100) - i do a calcumation 
        //2. some current value!
    }
    //Do the copying here
}
```

I keep having an issue with this line:

`classA.essentialBgWorker.ReportProgress(percents, i);`

This line worked when it was *in* ClassA - but once bringing it into ClassB gives an error:

`ClassA.essentialBgWorker' is inaccessible due to it's protection level`

Just looking for some assistance on the proper way to get it to fire from the other class.

Comment: Is "essentialBgWorker" a public?  And if so, make sure it is not static.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of essentialBgWorker in classA?

Comment: Updated the code with the declaration of the worker in ClassA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add public modifier to essentialBgWorker

```
public BackgroundWorker essentialBgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Comment: Bam, worked like a charm. Figures it would be something so simple!!

Comment: Semi related - but ClassA is a form (as you can see); currently when the ClassA is instantiated in ClassB - it loads a secondary form while the work is being performed.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Do you need ClassA to be a form?

Comment: Well, essentially I designed the form (ClassA) and then just wrote all the code to get it working within that class. Now I'm trying to 'clean it up' and make it more standardized by giving everything the appropriate classes. Should I move the background workers to their own non-form class? I only use them to update a progress bar (and I think since they're tied to the UI, they *belong* with the form (ClassA), correct?

Comment: I was able to figure it out - I passed in the form to the method and call it that way. pass it in with: `classA.copyDocuments(this)` then I get it on the class method with: `public void copyDocuments(ClassA classA)`, then I can access it with `classA.essentialBgWorker` and it works great.